# Galera Cluster(Status : mariadb server is down)

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, centos7, galera

Iam currently a DBA trainee. I am trying to configure Galera cluster in three different nodes in centos 7.While doing the process; I had to stop MariaDB. When I type *[root@localhost ~]# sudo systemctl stop MariaDB*
**[root@localhost ~]# sudo systemctl status MariaDB** it shows my MariaDB server is down. I alse tried df command; but my root is only 31% used. Please help me.
I am following this link
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-galera-cluster-with-mariadb-on-centos-7-servers?msclkid=b3b62f7bc60a11ecb34af23216d2c266
my node3

```
semodule -i Galera.pp

[root@localhost ~]# sudo semodule -i Galera.pp
[root@localhost ~]# sudo semanage permissive -d mysqld_t
libsemanage.semanage_direct_remove_key: Removing last permissive_mysqld_t module (no other permissive_mysqld_t module exists at another priority).
[root@localhost ~]# sudo systemctl stop mariadb
[root@localhost ~]# sudo systemctl status mariadb
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.4.24 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2022-04-27 15:18:27 +0545; 29s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/  Process: 13646 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13433 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13354 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13352 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 13433 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Apr 27 15:18:26 localhost.localdomain mysqld[13433]: ...
Apr 27 15:18:26 localhost.localdomain mysqld[13433]: ...
Apr 27 15:18:26 localhost.localdomain mysqld[13433]: ...
Apr 27 15:18:26 localhost.localdomain mysqld[13433]: ...
Apr 27 15:18:26 localhost.localdomain mysqld[13433]: ...
Apr 27 15:18:26 localhost.localdomain mysqld[13433]: ...
Apr 27 15:18:27 localhost.localdomain mysqld[13433]: ...
Apr 27 15:18:27 localhost.localdomain mysqld[13433]: ...
Apr 27 15:18:27 localhost.localdomain mysqld[13433]: ...
Apr 27 15:18:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: ...Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
[root@localhost ~]#  Status: "MariaDB server is down"-bash: Status:: command not found
[root@localhost ~]# df
Filesystem              1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                   495336       0    495336   0% /dev
tmpfs                      507376       0    507376   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      507376    6752    500624   2% /run
tmpfs                      507376       0    507376   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root   6486016 1982400   4503616  31% /
/dev/sda1                 1038336  140392    897944  14% /boot
tmpfs                      101476       0    101476   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: maybe you can get reason why the service is down from `journalctl` or looking in `/var/log`?

Comment: @Kristian thanks for your concern. My it shows like this:

Comment: 'Logs begin at Wed 2022-04-27 12:27:41 +0545, end at Wed 2022-04-27 16:38:30 +0545. --
Apr 27 12:27:41 localhost.localdomain systemd-journal[89]: Runtime journal is using 6.1M (max allowed 49.5M, trying to leave 74.3M free of 489.2M available → current limit
Apr 27 12:27:41 localhost.localdomain kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Apr 27 12:27:41 localhost.localdomain kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Apr 27 12:27:41 localhost.localdomain kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct'

Comment: Edit the question with more information if needed. There isn't the space/formatting in comments to communicate more than simple answers. What you show look like a clean and orderly shutdown. Given you did `systemctl stop mariadb` that is expected.